# Use a bash script to remove data from database?

Tags: database, shell

I am running shell script on Linux that downloads new data and put them into DB. It works fine. But I need to remove data from database older than today before I put there new one.

My question is: Should I put the database query directly into shell script or write separate program that only delete data and ends.
I am worried if I use database directly from shell, I have to put password there in a plain text and security is concern.

Comment: What RDBMS do you use ? You probably don't need the credentials when you run the script on the same host as the database server.

Comment: @PeterMmm PostgreSQL.. when I am connecting via terminal I have to enter password

Comment: Read about config [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and probably [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html).